# I can't find displacement method

Tags: displacement

I just recently got into blender and I'm transferring from Cinema 4D. I wanted to play around with the basic material components in the shader editor, but i got stuck at the displacement node. I noticed in the tutorial i followed that you have to enable in the displacement method "Displacement and bump" but I can't find that option in the material settings.[image: no displacement]

Comment: You likely have Eevee as your rendering engine. Change it to Cycles to see what you're looking for. Eevee doesn't support true mesh displacement at this time.

Comment: so im guessing I would have to use the classic subdivision displacement deformer method then huh?

Answer (score 1):

You need **Cycles** rendering engine for the displacement setting.

From your properties panel: Select *Scene* > *Render Engine* >> *Cycles*

[image]

After you select the right engine, the displacement properties will be visible and changeable.

[image]

Comment: Is there any other way I can add displacement without giving my mesh more subdivisions but still using Eevee?

Comment: @no_va Not for 2.80 and 2.81 now. It is hard to add the true displacement into EEVEE engine without adding extra vertex content in the pipeline. You still need to add the *displacement mod* with detail mesh for now.